# ¿Qué es una "máquina de coser para costura over"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

A friend is asking me to check the price for a *maquina de coser para costura over* in the U.S., to see if it's worth bringing with me to Mexico when I visit soon.  I don't know what that is.  She doesn't know how better to translate it to English.

Her description is:

> es una maquinita chiquita y tiene para que le insertes 4 hilos y hace la costura mira una camiseta tuya por dentro y las costuras de los lados si estan a la pura orilla pero como redondito o como por los 2 lados como que captura las 2 orillas y hace que no se deshile la ropa

How would one translate the name of this machine into English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an [overlock sewing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlock). The image from Wikipedia:

[image]

Also, part of the description, that resembles what your friend told you:

> An overlock stitch sews over the edge of one or two pieces of cloth
>   for edging, hemming or seaming. Usually an overlock sewing machine
>   will cut the edges of the cloth as they are fed through (such machines
>   are called ‘sergers’ in North America), though some are made without
>   cutters. The inclusion of automated cutters allows overlock machines
>   to create finished seams easily and quickly. An overlock sewing
>   machine differs from a lockstitch sewing machine in that it uses
>   loopers fed by multiple thread cones rather than a bobbin. Loopers
>   serve to create thread loops that pass from the needle thread to the
>   edges of the fabric so that the edges of the fabric are contained
>   within the seam.