# Equivalente en idioma inglés de La Real Academia Española

Tags: rae

¿Cuál es el equivalente de la Real Academia Española, en el contexto del idioma inglés?.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es off-topic, y estaría mejor situada en [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/) que aquí!

Comment: @jachguate yo no veo mala la pregunta, en si por la pregunta, y tambien por darle la bienvenida a alguien nuevo al sitio.(Es que si se recibe la gente diciendole que su pregunta no es válida loo más probable es que no vuelva)

Comment: No pretendo ser descortés con @rraalw, a quién por supuesto doy la bienvenida al sitio, e invito a leer la sección [what kind of questions can I ask here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq#qu-tipo-de-preguntas-puedo-hacer-aqu) de las [faq](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq). Sin embargo, no veo cómo está pregunta encaja dentro de este sitio.

Comment: @jachguate Bién, entiendo su preocupación. La razón para hacer la pregunta acá, es que a mi parecer es mucho más probable que un hispanohablante sepa de la RAE, que alquien angloparlante. Así que la pregunta seria quizá un tanto mas complicada de formular en la EL&U

Comment: @jachguate puede que tengas razón en que encaje o no. si se miran las reglas con lupa seguramente no encaje. Y tambien seguramente suceda con montones de preguntas. Es solo cuestión de cortesia y diplomacia.

Comment: Welcome to Spanish Language & Usage! Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here. It may be on-topic at [English L&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Si haces la pregunta en EL&U, haz referencia también a la "Academie Francais".  Puede ser más conocida que la RAE.

Comment: @Walter Mitty Gracias! es bueno saberlo.

Comment: @WalterMitty De verdad no entiendo nada que sentido, ni utilidad puede tener cerrar una pregunta cuando ya está respondida y aprobada la respuesta.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero, para que quede claro que no se aceptan precisamente preguntas que no tengan nada que ver con el castellano.

Comment: @JoulSauron http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/que-es-una-maquina-de-coser-para-costura-over pues hay tantas con menos relación con el español que esa pregunta que me voy formando mi criterio.

Comment: @Ernesto, la pregunta que enlazas contiene una duda sobre la traducción de una expresión en español, lo que según entiendo si está dentro del tópico del sitio. La idea es que, siendo este sitio sobre el uso de Español, no es el mejor lugar donde encontrar un _experto_ que pueda responder una pregunta que en realidad es sobre el uso del idioma inglés (como claramente es esta). Creo que no es solo por _ver con lupa_ las reglas, sino también ayudar al OP a encontrar el sitio donde encontrará la mejor respuesta a su pregunta.

Comment: there is no equivalent of RAE for English language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien oficialmente no existe ningun regulador de la lengua inglesa equivalente a la RAE: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_regulators

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_language

Si son autoridades Oxford University  que publica muchos manuales de estilo la más reconocida es **[Hart's Rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hart%27s_Rules)**

Para el inglés americano debe tomarse como estandar el Webster's Dictionary.

Aquí hay una **[discusión muy interesante acerca del tema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aList_of_language_regulators)**

Answer (score 1):

La lengua inglesa, como la gran mayoría de lenguas en el mundo, no ea regulada por entidades específicas. En el caso de la lengua castellana, esto fué una decisión política deliberada de la corona española para asegurar la homogeneidad en la comunicación de las colonias con la sede imperial y entre ellas y así facilitar el comercio y el control político y social (por religioso). Los otros respondientes ya te han dado algunas referencias al respecto.

Si en este momento de la historia nos es dificil comunicarnos entre nosotros, digamos un mejicano, un colombiano, un uruguayo, usando nuestras jergas dialectales nacionales, imagina cuan difícil sería hacerlo si nuestros dialectos no hubiesen tenido una fuerza cohesiva que impregnara los sectores cultos de nuestras sociedades. La influencia de las lenguas nativas habría sido tan fuerte que hablaríamos en jeringonza para todos los demás y aún dentro de los mismos paises las diferencias regionales serían mayúsculas.

Esto, por supuesto, no ocurrió con las áreas del mundo colonizadas por los ingleses, franceses o alemánes, simplemente porque las poblaciones nativas fueron efectivamente ignoradas y marginadas (como en la India o en el África) o exterminadas, como sucedió en el Norte de América.

Comment: A ok, entonces bajo estas aseveraciones, cabria preguntarse entonces, si la RAE es aun vigent hoy en día.

Comment: @rraallvv ¡Buena pregunta! Es algo que se preguntan muchos, aún en las academias nacionales. En mi opinión, la RAE es un mal necesario para mantener nuestra cohesión cultural, más que la idiomática. Me explico: El ingĺés se mantiene coherente gracias a los medios masivos de comunicación (todos ven CNN). El alemán y el francés tienen una cohesión cultural inherente que el castellano no tiene. Sin algo como la RAE, la lengua entraría en deriva especialmente en América. Por ejemplo, la academia nacional de los E.E.U.U. ha hecho maravillas para impedir que el castellano allí se vuelva un "pidgin".

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente no hay, aquí en este [articulo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo%3aAcademias_Ling%C3%BC%C3%ADsticas) se listan las academias lingüísticas en las cuales no se encuentra alguna para el ingles, pero  por lo que tengo entendido existen instituciones que se dedican a recopilar reglas gramaticales como las universidades de Oxford y Cambridge  entre otras...

Comment: De Acuerdo.  No hay.

Comment: Qué te da la impresión de que las universidades de Oxford y Cambridge se dedican a recopilar reglas gramaticales?